# Read the metadata of a XLSM file size 6MB -Apache POI 3.9-

Tags: apache-poi, apache-tika

I need to read XLSM file metadata, to files less than 4 MB The following instructions work correctly:

```
try {
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open (new FileInputStream ("C:\\Path to file.xlsm"));
XSSFWorkbook XSSFWorkbook = new document (pkg);
documento.getProperties poixmlProperties = ();
...
} catch (Exception ex) {
...
} finally {
...
}
```

For files larger than 4 MB does not run the second line `(XSSFWorkbook document=new XSSFWorkbook (pkg))`, jump directly to the finally block without giving any errors.

Comment: Have you tried using a `File` instead of a `FileInputStream` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't use an InputStream when you have a File object! Using an InputStream means POI has to buffer you whole thing into memory, while with a File it can leave it on disk until needed. As [covered in the POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), instead open with:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("file.xlsx"));
```

Secondly, you seem to be opening up the whole Excel structure and parsing that into memory, when all you want is the metadata. Don't! Firing up XSSFWorkbook takes quite a lot of processing and memory, which you don't need if all you care about is metadata, which lives in a separate area of the file

Instead, just load the properties themselves, and work with that. Your final code would be something like:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("file.xlsx"));
POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
System.out.println("The title is " + props.getCorePart().getTitle());
```

That ought to load in only a fraction of the file's total size as memory use

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification.
Now my question is how to save metadata modified into a new file and leave the original file intact.

Comment: The instruction pkg.close() saves all the changes made to the original file and I need that this file is not modified

Comment: Copy the original file to a new name, open the new name, change, save?

Comment: I thought there would be some parameter that could do this without having to do what you say. Thank you very much for your help.